# When answering a question, is it ethical to ask for a Google sheets file even when such a request violates a user's privacy?

Tags: discussion, behavior, privacy, personal-data

It is common in [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) for answerers to ask questioners to share a Google sheets file. Some requests in the last 24 hours:

- [How can I combine multiple functions with ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473152/how-can-i-combine-multiple-functions-with-arrayformula#comment106981279_60473152)
- [Can I put the 'query' part of a =QUERY in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463981/can-i-put-the-query-part-of-a-query-in-a-cell#comment106965596_60463981)
- [Google sheet dynamic value pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464527/google-sheet-dynamic-value-pivot-table#comment106966509_60464527)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472814/loop-through-api-data-array-to-get-specific-values-from-objects-for-comparison-w#comment106981071_60472814

Almost half or more of the questions in these tags has or is requested to have a sample spreadsheet.

The obvious advantages:

- Easier to visualize the data structure
- Easier to test an answer

The disadvantages and the point of this post:

1. Those links can easily be revoked after getting an answer- making the post unusable to future users.

   - This promotes sub-standard questions; questions which are not clearly explained or almost all explanations depend on the external link. However, the questioner gets an answer and the answerer gets their reputation, even if there is no net value added to the community.
2. Unbeknownst to the user sharing the spreadsheet, they are exposing their personal email address too. The email address of the questioner can usually be accessed by opening the spreadsheet>Share menu. Alternatively, if you don't want to open the spreadsheet, it is easily accessible from the following API. So, scrapers can easily get the data. You don't need a Google account. At the bottom of the page (*Try this API*), you just need to enter the spreadsheet id, set fields to `*`, disable OAuth and execute.

   - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

Furthermore comments such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424508/python-gspread-how-to-populate-google-sheet-dictionaries-within-list#comment106893336_60424508) give users a false sense of security as they are convinced that they had removed all sensitive information.

I understand that this boils down to whether users consider their email address private and whether they know that by sharing their spreadsheet, they are sharing their email address too. I believe they are unaware of the latter and hence this discussion.

Does the community see it is a violation of privacy? If so, what can be done to moderate the users participating in this tag? In my opinion, the data structure can clearly be shown in the question as csv or as a table as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60466903/) or a plain screenshot image- all of which add value to the question, answer and the community.

Related: [What to do when an OP posts someone's email address?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315384/)

*Note: I don't believe that there's any malicious intent behind any of the requesters/answerers.*

Comment: It is a violation of the base principle that a question should be self-contained.

Comment: It's not about ethics & privacy. It's about creating posts that depend on brittle external links to be useful. A question that depends on an external link to be answerable should be closed until that's not longer the case. An answer that depends on an external link, deleted as not an answer.

Comment: @usr2564 So, what can be done? None of the questions asked as such is closed because  high rep members are interested in answering the question rather than adding value to the question. What can be done  to avoid such a trend/culture?

Comment: I have found that a bigger problem than PII (email address - not really a big deal, IMHO), is that way too many Google Doc users simply do not understand how to share properly. They commonly do one of:
* Share read/write when they clearly want it to be read-only
* Share requiring specific email address to connect when they want it to be public/open
* Share public/open when they want to share only to specific people (not the case for SE/SO, but I see it all the time elsewhere)

Comment: I'm really a complete layman when it comes to GoogleSheets and the like, but would it be possible (or, at least, *feasible*) to have an SE-owned site where such spreadsheets could be copied to (along the lines of the imgur site for images). This would go a long way to resolve the issue raised by @yivi, but don't know if it could be used to 'clean up' sensitive info.

Comment: I think the problem lies when people share links and then revoke the access.
In regards to the ethics of asking to share information, the user that is sharing has control over whether or not such information will be shared.

From what I've saw, most time people ask for a copy of the spreadsheet is because the question is extremely data-specific and the OP failed to explained what is happening with other means. In these cases, should the question just be flagged as a Low Quality question?

Comment: @AdrianMole So you are suggesting Stack Overflow buy out Google Drive? :-D

Comment: @TheMaster There has been an Update to Google's Sharing Policy on View Only Google Sheets.  It no longer exposes the email address of the user.  I recognize that it is not an answer to this question in any way, but it's relevant and I thought I should share.

Comment: @MattKing Awesome. I think the information is relevant enough to add a answer here. Also if you're interested, you can add a answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114961/share-google-sheets-anonymously) too.

Comment: @MattKing Is the update live? I can still access the email address using the api test mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TheMaster Seems it might just be from the Share Button and from the Drive where the protection was enabled.

Comment: @MattKing You mean it's just a UI change? That's actually bad news. At least before,  privacy conscious people knew they were sharing their email address too as it was plainly in the UI. Now it's just hidden. Scrapers and bots will be very glad. If you are in touch with product experts, kindly ask them to reconsider.

Comment: Another facet to this that I didn't see anyone mention is that by clicking on a google sheets link [you can expose your own email](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739) unless you've configured your accounts privacy settings

Comment: @0x263A That's not true. The link you've posted only applies to "work/school account" and more importantly, it only applies to "view history". There is no setting to hide your email address, if you've shared a Google sheet publicly through  the "share" menu.

Comment: @TheMaster hm weird I've definitely seen people outside of my own orgs appear in the view history and [the first bullet under five here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7573825) backs up that theory...

Comment: @0x263A Not sure what point you're making, but email address is plainly visible to everyone, who shared the link publicly.

Comment: @TheMaster I wanted to make the tangential point that while the sharers email is publicly exposed, the recipient's can be as well (and they may not know that)

Comment: @0x263A It appears that my activity dashboard history is turned off by default, if this is the case then a recipient should be aware as they had to turn it on in the first place.

Comment: I would argue that by the very nature of google sheets one should already know to create a separate gmail just for public sharing if it is an issue. You can't even use google sheets effectively without sharing your email. How many people actually use google sheets over excel/libreoffice and do not collaborate with people whom perhaps they do not want to receive personal emails from. It's more of an ethical issue for google if people are not aware of this.

Comment: If it is an ethical issue to ask for a google sheet link from someone then it is more of an ethical issue for google to allow you to share a public link without any notification or warning that the link will be essentially publishing the email address associated with the account.

Comment: @CodeCamper Obviously Google is known to degrade user's privacy. It's a ad company after all. What Google does or doesn't do is out of scope for  Stackoverflow. We can only decide what our users do or are allowed to do. When a perfectly valid alternative exist(text table/screenshots), most users don't care about the question. They are trying to help the OP, not answer the question asked. That's not how SO should operate. It shouldn't matter who the asker is or whether they are helped, what matters is the content of the question and whether it's answerable and useful for future readers.

Comment: SO is meant to be a repo of high quality questions and answers. Not a support site for Google or a free help site or free code writing service for end users.

Comment: is it possible to insert a table that basically simulates the cells without the formulas functioning of course so that it could seamlessly copy into a google sheet?

Comment: @CodeCamper You can write a formula in a table. But it won't work in SO. When table is copy pasted,  formula will work.

Comment: I understand the formula won’t work but for a more complex situation I wonder if we can write it in a way where it can be seamlessly pasted into our own google sheet. (Multi cell issue)

Comment: @CodeCamper Copy paste this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143093/how-to-get-google-sheets-to-reliably-compare-text-cells-that-include-and The formula in C1 will be evaluated. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/74045896 for a table only question.

Comment: Maybe they can add a confirmation pop-up warning on stackoverflow when someone enters what looks like an email address or google sheet link letting them know this information will be shared publicly

Comment: @CodeCamper https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382675/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the latest support for [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support), I believe using tables solves a lot of the issues mentioned. I'm adding a answer, so users referred here might use tables instead of sharing a sheets file.

#### Advantages:

- Question becomes self contained
- Privacy - No email leak
- **Tables => Sheets**: Tables are easy to copy to sheets(Direct copy+paste works well on many platforms); When copied maintains the table structure in sheets as well: This eases the burden of Answerers. This solves the issue with [images mentioned by @Tedinoz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394649/)
- **Sheets => Tables**:

  ###### Detailed instructions to share a table from  sheets can be found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/).
- Makes the questioner think and assists in making a minimal example rather than sharing a full original bulky file.

#### Markdown sample:

> `Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.`

> Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 23):

In general, one can't violate one's own privacy (at least not in a legal sense). If the user shares material containing someone else's personal information, that would really be a problem. But sharing something that shows their own email address isn't problematic.

Besides privacy, I agree with the comments: All information must be included in the question itself. The spreadsheets may only be supplementary but the question also has to stand without it.

Comment: *But sharing something that shows their own email address isn't problematic.* Even if  they aren't aware that  they're doing so?  I'm not talking about legal ground. I'm talking in a ethical sense. Is it  ethical to ask a user to share something knowing full well that such user isn't aware that he would also be sharing his email?

Comment: @TheMaster People can do unethical things in comments. I can ask BDL to share their credit card number and CCV. If you see someone doing something unethical in the comments, flag the comment. The moderator may decline your flag, in which case you have your answer (for that moderator, for that comment, anyway).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Asking for a credit card is black and white- it's black and I don't think any mod will decline the flag. Here it's not so black and white. We can only create awareness of the issue and inform users effectively.

Answer (score -2):

I am one of those that who regularly asks a questioner: "Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding private or confidential information, and include an example of a successful outcome." I was ignorant of the exposure of a questioner's email address until this post was brought to my attention.

At face value, this post deals with the ethics of *misleading* questioners on Stack Overflow (and Web Applications too) about the security of their email address. This is a serious issue which can and should be promptly addressed.

Stack Overflow can, and should, deal with the ethics issue in a heartbeat:

1. include a relevant statement in the "Asking" section of the Help Center,

2. create a suitably worded shorthand link that can be used when requesting a copy of a spreadsheet,
3. educate users about the issue,
4. provide questioners with **practical** guidance about how to include data in csv and/or text table.

However, I respectfully suggest that the "ethics" issue is a red-herring and the actual subject of this post is the *self-contained question*; that rather than take pro-active steps to remedy the ethics issue, we prefer to engage in hand-wringing over whether a question should be self-contained. The principle of the self-contained question is admirable and it is one to strive for but, in the real world, it is not possible in every case. Not even the "Triage" queue, nor any reasons in "Close questions", consider self-containment.

In my admittedly limited experience, many questioners are hard-pushed to unambiguously describe their scenario, and/or what they are trying to achieve, and/or the nature of their problem. Asking them to provide data in csv or a text table sounds good in principle but problematic in practice. But, if it is a worthy objective, then let's get on with it - expand the "Asking" section of the Help Center and explain the risks and alternatives available to questioners.

The use of screenshots to provide details of data, or visualise/demonstrate the layout of a spreadsheet is something on which that we must agree to disagree. Except in limited cases, a screenshot demands too much time and effort from a user to construct a spreadsheet and include representative data before they even begin to deal with the mechanics of solving the questioner's problem. Advocating screenshots as an alternative would, I suggest, result in fewer comments and/or answers.

Comment: @TheMaster Interesting link on Google's 'Docs Editors Help' page [SHEETS Product Experts' – TIPS FOR POSTING](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en). No mention of involuntary disclosure of email address.

Comment: Yes. Most forums never mention it, but just ask the questioner to share file.  I see you posted a question there. Maybe experts there will consider modifying the help page. I believe you also found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114961/share-google-sheets-anonymously) already.

Comment: "nor any reasons in "Close questions", consider self-containment. " Well, except for the SO-specific "Needs debugging information - The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." The spirit of which encourages the code needed to be included in the question.

Answer (score -5):

I think, the majority of the spreadsheet questions in practice is not a programming one, or it is hard to ask them in an SO-compliant form. In their cases, maybe Super User would possibly be a better match.

Second, as others already said: the question must be comprehensible and answerable without the spreadsheet. If the user cannot explain their problem *without the spreadsheet*, the question is unclear or off-topic or link-only (most likely, all of them).

Comment: The topicality  of spreadsheet formulas has been discussed again and again. [The consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic/261927#261927) is that they're on-topic and a valid programming language.

Comment: @TheMaster What I agree. I just believe that the common requirements (like minimal verifiable example for debug questions) makes most of the spreadsheet problems practically un-askable here.

Comment: First Your doubt that a Google sheets question has anything to do with programming is baseless. Almost half of the questions tagged with Google sheets (16k/32k) are tagged  with [tag:google-apps-script]- a platform for JavaScript based automation. There is also a external [tag:google-sheets-api] for direct interaction  with sheets using other languages. Beyond that the rest of the questions are  usually about formulae. In which case, As my [answer states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404151/) tables solves most if not all problems in providing a minimal repro.

Comment: @TheMaster While I believe even the first form was enough clear, I edited the post to make it yet more clear. Of course I have no problem with spreadsheets questions (any script language is a programming language -> obviously on-topic).